# Issues with textfinder and IF

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I have a piece of code that was scrounged together from another code that is known working.  What it does is searches a column using textfinder for a value, in this case, yesterday's date, if nothing is found, it should send an email.

```
function findAndSendMail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FormResponses');
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('AlertDate');
  var search = ss2.getRange("B2").getValue(); //cell has yesterday's date
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange(1,4,lastRow); //define range for column D, column D contains dates
  //find all occurrences of search key in column D and push range to array
  var ranges = range.createTextFinder(search).findAll();

if (ranges!==null) {
  var message = '';
  }else {
  var message = 'Test';
  }

  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EmailGroup").getRange("A1");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

  var subject = 'Subject';
  var link = "blahblahblah"

  if (message) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,  '**This is an automated message**\n\n' + message + '\n\n**This is an automated message**\n' + link);
  }
}
```

As you see, it should search column D, then, if it finds something, the message variable will be blank, else if it finds nothing, it will send an email to the email addresses chosen.  I'm not sure how the results from a textfinder work with this and I think the way it is written is incorrect.  Any help is appreciated, unfortunately, I cannot share the document in question as my company doesn't allow sharing outside of the domain.  Thank you!

Comment: Is the contents  of  B2 a string or a date, because textFinder searches for text or regular expressions. Same question about column D.

Comment: Good point.  It is a formula, =today()-1

Comment: Try my answer.  See if it will work for you.  I might need to change getValues() to getDisplayValues();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You will need to update the sheet names I moved them to end of the line comments

```
function findAndSendMail() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//FormResponses
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//AlertDate
  var d1=new Date(sh2.getRange("B2").getValue()); //cell has yesterday's date
  var d2=new Date(d1.getFullYear(),d1.getMonth(),d1.getDate()).valueOf();
  var rg1 = sh1.getRange(1,4,sh1.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg1.getValues().map(function(r){
    var dt=new Date(r[0]);
    var dtv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
    return dtv;
  });
  if(vA.indexOf(d2)==-1) {
    var message='test';
    var emailAddress = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange("A1").getValue();//EmailGroup
    var subject = 'Subject';
    var link = "blahblahblah"
  }
  if (message) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,  '**This is an automated message**\n\n' + message + '\n\n**This is an automated message**\n' + link);
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('I found something');//just for testing
  }
}
```

This version sends an email if yesterday is not found.

In answer to you last question:

```
function findAndSendMail() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//FormResponses
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//AlertDate
  var d1=new Date(sh2.getRange("B2").getValue()); //cell has yesterday's date
  if(isDate(d1)) {
    var d2=new Date(d1.getFullYear(),d1.getMonth(),d1.getDate()).valueOf();
    var rg1 = sh1.getRange(1,4,sh1.getLastRow(),1);
    var vA=rg1.getValues().map(function(r){
      var dt=new Date(r[0]);
      var dtv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
      return dtv;
    });
    if(vA.indexOf(d2)==-1) {
      var message='test';
      var emailAddress = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3").getRange("A1").getValue();//EmailGroup
      var subject = 'Subject';
      var link = "blahblahblah"
      }
    if (message) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,  '**This is an automated message**\n\n' + message + '\n\n**This is an automated message**\n' + link);
      //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('I found something');//just for testing
    }
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Data is sheet2!B2 is not a date')
    return;
  }
}

function isDate(date){ 
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]'); 
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work.  I've updated the sheet names.  I currently have yesterday's date in B2 of AlertDate, there are no matching dates in FormResponses and I am not receiving a notification in my email.  I'm sorry to not offer anything else helpful, I am trying to decipher the code you gave me but it is a bit beyond my capabilities.

Comment: Okay, I changed the date to a date that is found within FormResponses and I get the message.  Is this code set up to send the message when there is nothing found matching or when something is found?

Comment: Actually, I think I got it.  I just changed it to an else after the if.                                                  
```if(vA.indexOf(d2)!=-1) {
  }else{
    var message='test';
    var emailAddress = ss.getSheetByName("EmailGroup").getRange("A1").getValue();//EmailGroup
    var subject = 'test';
    var link = "blahblahblah"
  }```

Comment: Actually all you have to do  is this `if(vA.indexOf(d2)==-1) {`

Comment: Great!  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Question, if the field I am using to trigger this (yesterday's date) isn't a date, how would I prevent the email from sending?  I've tried using an if (d1 == NaN) {} else if (vA.indexOf(d2)==-1) but it still sends an email.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a date, as long as it's a string that the Date() constructor recognizes.  If you want to test for it being a date you can use this `function isDate(date){
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}`